# Permission level for setting Log level without being root

Tags: mongodb

I have a user with the roles userAdminAnyDatabase and readWriteAnyDatabase. But this does not seem to be enough to set log level for my database. So what permissions do I need to set without having to make my user root?

This is the error I get:

```
[thread1] Error: setLogLevel failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { setParameter: 1.0, logComponentVerbosity: { verbosity: 3.0 } }",
    "code" : 13
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Before use administrative command you need select `admin` database:

```
use admin
```

Also you need `hostManager` role or permission `setParameter` for cluster resource.

Read more about [administrative command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/#instance-administration-commands), [admin database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-admin-database) and [setParameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setParameter/#dbcmd.setParameter)

`setLogLevel` use administrative command `setParameter`:

```
function (logLevel, component) {
    componentNames = [];
    if (typeof component === "string") {
        componentNames = component.split(".");
    } else if (component !== undefined) {
        throw Error("setLogLevel component must be a string:" + tojson(component));
    }
    var vDoc = {verbosity: logLevel};

    // nest vDoc
    for (var key, obj; componentNames.length > 0;) {
        obj = {};
        key = componentNames.pop();
        obj[key] = vDoc;
        vDoc = obj;
    }
    var res = this.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, logComponentVerbosity: vDoc});
    if (!res.ok)
        throw _getErrorWithCode(res, "setLogLevel failed:" + tojson(res));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you add you user profile in question? `db.system.users.findOne({'user':'username'})`

Comment: {
 "_id" : "admin.user-1",
 "user" : "user-1",
 "db" : "admin",
 "credentials" : {
  "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
   "iterationCount" : 10000,
   "salt" : "VOUobpZnK4qpyTxbhg6OmQ==",
   "storedKey" : "nO/KVPiG6HBSlC8cXq3cZtkfw0o=",
   "serverKey" : "TwallVu8EFEA7RclrATYKwpUzmE="
  }
 },
 "roles" : [
  {
   "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
   "db" : "admin"
  },
  {
   "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
   "db" : "admin"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Are you use replica set or sharded cluster?

Comment: No replica set or sharded cluster. Running on a single instance

Comment: How do you run `mongod`? I try to understand your env.

Comment: I use systemctl and my mongod.service file has the --auth flag